# Missing Android Icon

Tags: android, icons, missing-features

I've edited and added features from a programme which has involved adding another class (not activity class) since then when I load the app onto my android device I cannot see an icon appear but the app appears in the Application Manager. I have no errors showing and have commented out each section of the new class to turn it back to the original app. Could anyone tell me whether the problem is most likely to be in the manifest, the main.xml or the activity class? Or if they have come across a similar problem?

Cannot publish code due to company policy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myAppName" <!-- real package name cannot be supplied -->
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


        <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
     <provider
        android:name="com.example.MyAppName.ProviderClassName"
        android:authorities="com.example.MyAppName.ProviderClassName"
     />

    </application>



</manifest>
```

Comment: Check if in the manifest file it says :  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" and if so, then if it is also an avaialble icon. see if it is in the drawable folders. otherwise you can automatically get the correct icons.

Comment: If you do not show the manifiest content is impossible to see that you may be doing wrong.

Comment: The manifest has a reference to a drawable as the app-icon. I find it difficult to imagine that google didn't have an answer for you.

Comment: Thank you, I have added the manifest I am allowed to. It has the ic_launcher which is located in the drawable folder